# Does Hammerblow stack with Mighty Swing or Dual Weapon Mastery?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

I'm trying to make a character based on STR and DEX to do great unarmed melee attacks. Now I am wondering: does the **Hammerblow** talent of the soldier **stack** with the **Mighty Swing** feats?

As far as I know, the hammerblow doubles my STR bonus as long as the character wields no weapon.

In order to make it clear, here is my character sheet:

Large Yuzzem soldier 6
Force 8
Init +10; Senses scent; Perception +2
Languages Draethos, Twi'lek, Yuzz

Defenses Ref 20 (flat-footed 16), Fort 18, Will 15
hp 58; Threshold 23

Speed  6 squares
Melee claw +10 (1d12+8) or
Melee claw +14 (1d12+8) with Hammerblow or
Melee claw +10 (2d12+8) with Mighty Swing
Ranged  by weapon +8
Fighting Space 2x2; Reach 1 square
Base Atk +6; Grp +15
Atk Options Echani Training, Hammerblow, Melee Defense, Mighty Swing, Unrelenting Assault

Abilities Str 19, Dex 15, Con 10, Int 14, Wis 8, Cha 8
Special Qualities expert climber, physical intimidation
Talents Hammerblow, Melee Smash, Unrelenting Assault
Feats Armor Proficiency (light, medium), Echani Training, Martial Arts I, Martial Arts II, Melee Defense, Mighty Swing, Weapon Proficiency (pistols, rifles, simple weapons)
Primary Skills Climb +12 (may take 10 even when distracted or threatened), Initiative +10, Jump +12, Persuasion +2 (+7 to intimidate), Stealth +0, Swim +12, Use Computer +10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes.

The Hammerblow Talent from Legacy Era: Campaign Guide says

> If you are unarmed and holding no items, you double your Strength bonus on unarmed attack rolls.

while the Mighty Swings feat from Star Wars: Saga Edition Core Rulebook says

> You can spend two swift actions in the same round to deal +1 die of damage on your next melee attack in the same round. The effects of this feat do not stack with the extra damage provided by the Rapid Strike feat.

There isn't an explicit nor implicit obstacle to the stacking of this two things.

The first requires a condition: Not holding a weapon or an item.

The second requires an action expenditure: 2 swifts.

As long as your character can satisfy both (an easy task, I'd say ^^), he will receive double Strength bonus on his unarmed attacks and an extra die of damage :)